# JsonPath OR condition using MockMVC

Tags: spring, junit, jsonpath, mockmvc, spring-rest

I am practicing MockMVC for rest call unit testing. how can we test the Boolean values so that whether the result is true or false I need to pass the test, I tried as follows,

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/student/{Id}", 1L)).
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.isPass", is(true  || false)));
```

Also I have list with 6 values, how can use list contains all kind of method,

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.subjectList", hasSize(5)))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.subjectList.name", Matchers.contains("English", "Hindi", "France", "Tamil", "Bengali"))
```

Any suggestions please!!

Comment: I assume, that your code just misses a method call: `... .andExpect(jsonPath("$.isPass", is(true  || false)).exists());`

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It is not working for me

Comment: What  error are you getting ?

Comment: can you provide the student class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest the use of hamcrest AnyOf logical matcher

Form the [Tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) :

> anyOf - matches if any matchers match, short circuits  (like Java ||)

So in your case:

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.AnyOf.*;

mockMvc.perform(get("/student/{Id}", 1L)).
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.isPass", anyOf(is(false),is(true))));
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.subjectList.name", anyOf(is("English"),is("Hindi")…)));
```

Somtime the  usage of hamcrest with Junit and some mock libs can be tricky
see

[How to use JUnit and Hamcrest together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569394/how-to-use-junit-and-hamcrest-together)