# How to use the isA-Matcher

Tags: java, junit, junit4, matcher, assertthat

I have a certain method that delivers a `Restriction`-object (where `Restriction` is an interface). And since its implementation is already testet, I just want to test if my method actually delivers a `RestrictionImpl`-object. 
I saw that there are matchers which I can use together with `assertThat` and I thought, that the `isA`-matcher is the thing want for this task.

Simplified my code looks like that:

```
public static Restriction getRestriction() {
    return new RestrictionImpl();
}
```

and my test looks like that;

```
@Test
public void getRestriction_returnsRestrictionImpl() {
    assertThat(getRestriction(), isA(RestrictionImpl.class));
}
```

However this won't compile. All I could do is test, if a `RestrictionImpl` is a `Restriction`... but there is no point in doing this.

Am I misunderstanding to purpose of `isA`? And what is it acually meant for?

UPDATE:
Using `assertThat(getRestriction(), is(instanceOf(RestrictionImpl.class)))` would work, but I thought that `isA` is a shortcut for exactly that.
Calling `assertThat` in the way I want would require it to have the signature `assertThat(T, Matcher<? extends T>)`, but its signature is `assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>)`

Comment: I think that what you mean is `assertThat(getRestriction().getClass(), isA(RestrictionImpl.class))` or `assertThat(getRestriction(), isA(instanceOf(RestrictionImpl.class)))`.

Comment: both wont compile either. Hower testing `assertThat(getRestriction(), is(instanceOf(RestrictionImpl.class))` would work but I though `isA` is a shortcut to that.

Comment: The signature of assertThat is `assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)` requires the type of Matcher should be <? super T>. But in your code, `RescrictionImpl.class` is not a type `Rescriction.class`, so it compiles failed.  To solve this problem, You can either change your code to `assertThat(getRestriction(), isA(Restriction.class));`  or change the signature of the getRestriction to `public static RestrictionImpl getRestriction()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an issue describing my problem: 
https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/27

And it looks like `isA` simply has the wrong signature in this version of junit. It is meant to be shortcut for `is(isIntanceOf(...))`, but it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want use [instanceOf](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#instanceOf(java.lang.Class)). And you know, those things all have javadoc available in the open. Where isA ... should be exactly what you need. So the problem might be: do you have the required hamcrest core matchers library in your project setup? In other words: maybe you should read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569394/how-to-use-junit-and-hamcrest-together).

And just some example code, from one of my own projects:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
...
@Test
public void testWhatever() throws IOException, ApiException {
    try { ...
        fail("should have thrown");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // as expected
        assertThat(e.getCause(), is(instanceOf(SomeClass.class)));
```

So, do you have those imports there?
Do you have the libraries in your project setup to back those imports?

Comment: "isA(java.lang.Class<T> type)  A shortcut to the frequently used is(instanceOf(SomeClass.class))."

Comment: I was also wondering about the signature of `assertThat` since it is `assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>` but I want to use it like `assertThat(T, Matcher<? extends T>`

Comment: And yes, I have all dependencies and I have all the imports. With `is(instanceOf(RestrictionImpl.class))` it would work... but I thought `isA` is a shortcut for exactly that

Comment: Then the only thing left would be questioning the exact versions of the libraries.