# How can I use Mockito in my Android app itself? I'm receiving Hamcrest dependency conflicts that I don't receive when it's used only in tests

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mockito, junit4, gradle-dependencies

I'd like to use Mockito's `mock()` and `clone()` methods in the release version of an app I'm writing, not just in the tests. (Yes, I know what tests are, I'm not worried about performance, and I have [a reason for this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/37211/23786).) But when I include Mockito as a run-time dependency, my project does not compile. It compiles fine as a test dependency in **`app/build.gradle`**, using Mockito 1.10.19, Dexmaker 1.4, and Espresso 2.2.2:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:1.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.4'
}
```

But when I try to change these to run-time dependencies like so:

```
compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
compile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.4'
compile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:1.4'
compile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.4'
```

Gradle returns the following error trying to build the project with the `build` or `assembleAndroidTest` tasks, during the `prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies` task:

> Conflict with dependency 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core'. Resolved versions for app (1.1) and test app (1.3) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

I can see in the `dependencies` Gradle task that Mockito 1.10.19 depends on Hamcrest 1.1, and JUnit 4.12 depends on Hamcrest 1.3, but this error is odd to me for two reasons:

1. I didn't get this error when they were `testCompile` and `androidTestCompile` dependencies, but they were all being used then. It seems to me like I didn't add any new test dependencies, so why do they conflict now?
2. `assembleRelease` and `assembleDebug` complete without any errors.

What can I do to use Mockito in both the tests and the release build of my app?

I tried a couple things, with no success:

- duplicating the Mockito and Dexmaker dependencies, specifying them both as normal and as test dependencies.
- using Mockito 2. I tried the current version 2.2.22, and also 2.1.0, but with either I got a similar error trying to use `mock()` in a JUnit test:

  ```
  java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.android.dx.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.isTypeMockable(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockMaker$TypeMockability;

      at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
      at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
      at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:168)
      at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:162)
      at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
      at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1637)
      at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1550)
  ```

  From what I can find online, it looks like there's no current way for Mockito 2.x to work on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using older versions of some dependencies: JUnit 4.10 and Espresso 2.1. This changes the dependencies that were for Hamcrest 1.3 to Hamcrest 1.1, so that everyone's using 1.1. On my real project (not the test example in my question), I also had to use the `junit-dep` artifact instead of the `junit` one. (This is probably because of [a difference between the JUnit artifacts for versions 4.10 and 4.11+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353554/3004881), where the `junit:4.10` artifact includes some Hamcrest classes in it that the `junit-dep:4.10` and `junit:4.11+` artifacts don't.) So the dependencies become:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit-dep:4.10'

compile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
compile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.4'
compile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:1.4'
compile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.4'
```

Comment: This works for my purposes (so far, at least). But I have no idea why `androidTest` tests built and ran correctly with these supposedly-conflicting dependencies when Mockito was an `androidTestCompile` dependency. If anyone can explain why, or knows how to get more recent versions of these packages to work together, please write an answer, too!